# Several runActions one after another?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skaction

Is it possible to runAction on different nodes in a sequence style?

Maybe something like:

```
    [_parentSprite runAction: [SKAction sequence:@[actionOntheParent,
      [_secondSprite runAction: otherActionOnChildMaybe], [_someSprite runAction: actionOnSomeOtherSprite]]];
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you referring to running additional actions based on completion of previous action or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely, You can nest the actions using the completion block.

```
[_parentSprite runAction:actionOnTheParent completion:^{
        [_secondSprite runAction:otherActionOnChild completion:^{
            [_someSprite runAction:actionOnSomeOtherSprite];
        }];
    }];
```